# Call function after dispatch? (Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux

I'm working on a React app with Firebase. I want to call the first function after the `dispatch` is done. Each user is assigned a `currentcity`, but I don't want the `currentcity` to be one that is deleted because that would break the app. So what I'm trying to do is run the changeCurrentCity function after the deleteCity function is called so that this doesn't happen. I'm just trying to assign the currentcity to the first in the list.

`changeCurrentCity()` is not running from within the `.then()` of `deleteCity`. I've tried console.log-ing it and it just shows the function itself. I'm sure this is just a simple fix but I don't know what I'm doing.

```
const changeCurrentCity = (city) => {
    return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase, getFirestore }) => {
        const firestore = getFirestore();
        const userId = getState().firebase.auth.uid;
        firestore.collection('users').doc(userId).update({
            currentcity: city
        }).then(() => {
            dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_CITY', city });
        }).catch((err) => {
            dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_CITY_ERROR', err});
        })
    }
};

const deleteCity = (city) => {
    return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase, getFirestore }) => {
        const firestore = getFirestore();
        firestore.collection('cities').doc(city.id).delete().then(() => {
            dispatch({ type: 'DELETE_CITY', city });
        }).then(() => {
            changeCurrentCity(getState().firestore.data.cities[Object.keys(getState().firestore.data.cities)[0]].userid);
        }).catch((err) => {
            dispatch({ type: 'DELETE_CITY_ERROR', err});
        })
    }
};

export {changeCurrentCity, deleteCity}
```

The problem is in `deleteCity`. `changeCurrentCity` is not running after the city is deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dispatch action is asynchronous, that's why the changeCity is probably called immediately after the dispatch without the store being updated. You can await the dispatch with asnyc and resolve the promise after that. This will delay the changeCity until delete is done.

Comment: Thank you! That was helpful